# I can't find Android Studio Monitor after installation

Tags: android-studio

I am novice in Android Studio. I set up the application using a tutorial. But connect my android device with the Studio. Moreover, I can't find the "Monitor" box.
N.B: I have enabled USB debugging from my phone.

**[This is the latest window i got after installation]**

[image]

Comment: Android monitor was replaced by Android profiler in Android Studio 3.0 [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

View > Tool Windows > Android Monitor.

for more info

https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html